# Android/Libgdx Adding an Fragment to GoogleMaps FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, libgdx

So i have an problem... I want to add an SpriteLayer to my GoogleMaps FragmentActivity, for drawing and displaying Menus,Enemys and stuff like that.

First i create my GoogleMaps FragmentActivity like this :

```
public class GoogleMaps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks,GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

View mapView;

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

FutureTask<PlayFabErrors.PlayFabResult<PlayFabClientModels.LoginResult>> loginTask = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    GameFragment fragment = new GameFragment();

    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    trans.add(R.id.map,fragment);

    trans.commit();

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);


    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));


    // Move the camera instantly to location with a zoom of 15.
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 20));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17.5f), 2000, null);



    mapView = mapFragment.getView();

    mapView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int width = mapView.getMeasuredWidth();

            int height = mapView.getMeasuredHeight();

            String widthAndHeight = width + " " + height;

            Log.println(Log.ERROR,"Width and height :",widthAndHeight);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {


}

public static class GameFragment extends AndroidFragmentApplication
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return initializeForView(new Main());
    }

}

@Override
public void exit() {


}
}
```

As you can see i call this for adding the Fragment in the onCreate method :

```
GameFragment fragment = new GameFragment();

FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

trans.add(R.id.map,fragment);

trans.commit();
```

This should create a new static GameFragment, which is defined in the GoogleMaps FragmentActivity :

```
 public static class GameFragment extends AndroidFragmentApplication
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return initializeForView(new Main());
    }

}
```

At this points it returns the Main ApplicationAdapter class from Libgdx as an Fragment. Which is added to the `R.id.map`, the map layout from GoogleMaps.

Heres what the Main class looks like :

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;

Texture img;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
}

@Override
public void render () {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    img.dispose();
}
```

}

It just draws an Picture.

When i start the app now, the behavior is very strange. First the Libgdx Fragment Pops up for 1 second. Right after that it is "gone". Then the GoogleMap is loaded, but the touch events seems to be broken, because i cant zoom/move the map anymore.

So what did i do wrong ?

Thanks for your help !Im glad for every help i can get :D !

Comment: Hopefully it may be your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163321/android-java-custom-view-on-googlemaps-fragmentactivity-isnt-shown

Comment: @AbhishekAryan maybe its a bit weierd... but thats the link to one of my questions :-)